Docker host network works only under sudo
Maybe someone has encountered this problem.
It is NOT working!!!!
docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx


Nginx container is ok!
I can attach to it and run for example curl http://localhost:80 in the container and get the correct response.
But if I run this command on the host I don't get the response. I get error connection refused.
Also I don't see port in the list of listening ports on the host.


It is working!!!!
SUDO docker run --rm -d --network host --name my_nginx nginx


I see port 80 in port list on the host!
I can run curl http://localhost:80 on the host and get the correct response.

Details:

Just after docker Install, I added my user to docker group to access
demon Unix socket

I also have problem with other ports, 11181 for example. Not only 80

I have this problem on only ONE VM. Other VMs work fine -- without sudo. How can I
debug it?



you mention VMs, but this is about docker. Did you mean "containers"?

VM is host computer in this context. I try to run docker containers on this host

You definitely need specific privileges (being root or having CAP_NET_BIND_SERVICE) to bind ports lower than 1024. This is independent of you using docker.
That means no matter whether your rootless docker approach allows your container to use the host network namespace or not, it will need these privileges.
Generally: --network host for a HTTP service sounds like the opposite of what you'd usually want to do with containers. --publish the ports needed, and don't let your container interfere with your host's networking! A container started as root with --network host can do pretty much arbitrary things to your system – including telling docker to do arbitrary things.

Yes, I want that container can do pretty much arbitrary things to my system! :) I know about -p option with bridge network. But in my situation I have to switch to --network host. It works well (--network host) on other computer (other VM)
